# setting and retrieving session variables between class and controller MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, oracle11g, dataset

In my MVC application, I have a class with a function where I set  value to session variable

```
namespace Staffs.Libs
{
    public class ClassA
    {`.......`
   HttpContext.Current.Session["SessionID"] = intsessionId;
}
}
```

Need to get value of this Session in another controller

```
 [HttpGet]
     [AllowAnonymous]
     public ActionResult PrintDirectorytoPDF(string title)
     {

         string _SessionID = HttpContext.Session["SessionID"].ToString();
}
```

But  this is throwing error =  "object reference not set to an instance of any object"
What is that  I am doing wrong?

Comment: Hi guys.. any clue as to what is wrong!

Comment: You can set a `Session` property in a class. The class does not have access to the current request (unless you have injected it)

Answer (score 0):

If you're in an action method in a controller what you wrote should work. Otherwise try:

```
var sessionId = Session["SessionID"] as string;
```

But my guess is that your problem is actually that the session doesn't contain the `SessionID` value, and thus you're getting a null-pointer thrown when trying to `ToString()` the null found when looking in the session for the `SessionID`.

Comment: [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult ActionA()
        { Session["genID"] = "test";} [httpGet]   [AllowAnonymous] public ActionResult ActionB(){  var sessionId = Session["genID"].ToString(); } Even this  is showing null exception - I am not sure whats the issue.. Any clue

Comment: Should I define if anywhere else in global.ascx and then assign value here in controller??

Comment: check if any of these suggestions can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11668762/tempdata-session-in-mvc4-iis6-not-returning-stored-values?rq=1